# Find the largest prime factor of $3(3(3(3(3(3(3(3(3(3(3+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What I have done is that I found the expression is equal to $1+3+3^2+3^3+\cdots \cdots3^{11}=\frac{3^{12}-1}{2}$.

Then is there any way to find the prime factors of a number in such expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$a^6-1=(a^3-1)\times(a^3+1)=(a-1)(a^2+a+1) \times (a+1)(a^2-a+1)$
$a^6+1=(a^2)^3 + 1^3 = (a^2+1)(a^4-a^2+1)$

Comment: Shoot.......... I must have been too exhausted not seeing this..... Thanks a lot buddy...

Comment: @Ximing You're welcome :)

Comment: You should have factorised $a^{12}-1$, whereby you get that the largest prime factor is $73$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel $a^6-1$ also works for $a=9$ since $a^2-a+1=73$. I've added $a^6+1$ for bonus ;)

Comment: Yes, yes, yes...

Answer (score 1):

So the motive of this equation is that the value of $n$ is added by $1$ then multiplied by $n$ repeating this for $11$ times. That value after some calculation is $797,160$.

So now let's try dividing this by all prime numbers up to the result.

The biggest value at this point is $73$, so that's my guess.

---

So as mentioned of the hint by **[@Adola](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/406858/adola)**, I decided to give it a go and try to prove it.

What I got was: $728$ at the first equation then $730$ in the other one where $ a = 3 $. However, they're even numbers so that means they're not the values we should look for. If its any value other than $3$ that's used, there could be a possibility that there'd be more prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's just 111 111 111 111 base 3, which one can find the factorisation from the cunningham project.  The largest factor is in a12, which is 81-9+1 = 73.  The factors of a2, a3, a4, a6 are 4, 13, 10, 7.  So i guess it's $2^3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 13 \times 73$.